# Wait publishProgress finish before continue excute doInBackground AsyncTask android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My `AsyncTask` look like:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Data>> {
  private volatile UserData userData;
  protected List<Data> doInBackground(String... params) {
      // do some job 1
      publishProgress();
      // wait until the progress finish to update variable.
      if(userData!= null){
        //do some job 2
      }

      //do some job 3

  }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // try to ask user and collect information
        userData= getData();
    }

}
```

The problem is when I call `publishProgress()`, it still execute job 3 in `doInBackground`. How can I wait onProgressUpdate complete before continue?

**Update**:
In the getData() method, I tried to get the current location of user, which can't work in doInBackground and some other information from the view. I have to do this cause the job 1 take a very long time, and the current location of user can be changed. I need the most exactly location of user.

Comment: use wait and notify, that's what they are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the way you are using doInBackground and publishProgress() is something wrong, but still I need to see the code of method **getData()** .

**doInBackground** method should be used to do some task, which should be executed in other thread than event thread, and in **publishProgress** method, you should execute tasks which works with event thread. So, if **getData()** has nothing to do with event thread, please write the code in **doInBackground** itself.

However, if your requirements are just use both these methods, as present, then you can add a synchronize block, as like below:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Data>> {
  private volatile UserData userData;
  protected List<Data> doInBackground(String... params) {

  synchronize(userData)
  {
      // do some job 1
      publishProgress();
      // wait until the progress finish to update variable.
      if(userData!= null){
        //do some job 2
      }

      //do some job 3
    }
  }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // try to ask user and collect information
        synchronize(userData)
        {
            userData= getData();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have updated my question, I need to get location data from  getData() method.

Comment: jeet can you also explain the use of volatile and synchronize in it. What I know that volatile object can be changed by multiple threads at the same time. While synchronize(locking) means single thread can work on thread.

Answer (score 0):

use a flag _publishFinished = false; then call publish progress then do busy waiting in doInBackgrnd

```
`if(!_publishFinish) 
{Thread.Sleep(200);}`
```

at end of 
onProgressUpdate call

```
_publisFinish = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Data>>{


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
  private volatile UserData userData;
  protected List<Data> doInBackground(String... params) {
      // do some job 1
      publishProgress();
      // wait until the progress finish to update variable.
      if(userData!= null){
        //do some job 2
      }

      //do some job 3

  }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // try to ask user and collect information
        userData= getData();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            // closing progress dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

}
```

pDialog is your progress dialog. initialize from anywhere of your activity like this:

```
  ProgressDialog pDialog;
```

This will might help you.