# Can't update the UI with AsynckTask on Android

Tags: android-asynctask, artificial-intelligence

I am making an AI version of game 2048. After the game tree is created in background, I want to update the UI with `asynctask`. It doesn't work for now.
This is where I use the `AsyncTask` in `MainActivity.java;`

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... v) {
        try {
            Tree tree = new Tree(gameEngine);
            List<Node> path;

            Node root = new Node(gameEngine.grid.cells);

            tree.createInitialTree(root);
            path = ai.findPath(root);
            Node maxNode = path.get(path.size() - 1);

            for (Node node : path) {
                SystemClock.sleep(500);
                publishProgress(node.getDir());
            }

            while (!maxNode.myLose && (gameEngine.grid.areCellsAvailable(maxNode.getBoard()) || gameEngine.availableTileMatchLeft(maxNode)
                    || gameEngine.availableTileMatchRight(maxNode) || gameEngine.availableTileMatchUp(maxNode) ||
                    gameEngine.availableTileMatchDown(maxNode))) {
                tree = new Tree(gameEngine);
                tree.createTree(maxNode);

                path = ai.findPath(maxNode);

                for (Node node : path) {
                    SystemClock.sleep(500);
                    publishProgress(node.getDir());
                }

                maxNode = path.get(path.size() - 1);

            }
            System .out.println("You lose!!!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... direction) {
        switch (direction[0]) {
            case "left": onLeftSwipe();
                break;
            case "right": onRightSwipe();
                break;
            case "down": onDownSwipe();
                break;
            case "up": onUpSwipe();
                break;
        }
        super.onProgressUpdate(direction);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

    }
}
```

Calling it from `onCreate()`;

```
    AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
    runner.execute();
```

With `publishProggress(path)`, I am sending the list `path` which has the moves that the AI will do. But when it comes to the `onProggressUpdate()` and execute the `onSwipeLeft()` for example, it does not update the game screen. Am I using `AsyncTask` correctly? Thank you for your help.

UPDATE: It is now updating the `UI` but doesn't wait for the `publishProggress()` to finish. How do I do that?

Comment: what onSwipeLeft is doing? I guess the problem is there!

Comment: It moves the tiles to the left. It is working normally, when AI is not activated. @WasiAhmad

Comment: so, you believe the problem is probably in AI logic?? then you can debug to see, what your AI logic is doing in particular situations! i don't see any problem in the code you provided.

Comment: I believe the problem is in `AsyncTask`. I've never used it before, maybe there is something wrong with it. I think AI logic is correct, debugged but couldn't find the problem. There are two `publishProgress()` method in `doInBackground()`, is it right way to use?  @WasiAhmad

Comment: Yes, its fine. According to me you are doing just one thing wrong, i am not sure whether that is the reason or not! I have mentioned that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you have commented out the statement: `super.onProgressUpdate(path);` inside your `onProgressUpdate` method. You shouldn't do that.

Since you are using `asynctask` for the first time, i am giving you a very simple example that updates UI components (textview and a progressbar) from `asynctask`.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView textOut1, textOut2, textOut3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // required codes goes here
    }

    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //In UI thread, you can access UI here
            super.onPreExecute();
            String s1 = textIn1.getText().toString();
            textOut1.setText(s1);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
                SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                publishProgress(i);  //update UI in onProgressUpdate

                //Can GET from UI elements
                String s2 = textIn2.getText().toString();

                final String msgInBackGround = "doInBackground: " + i + " - " + s2;

                /*
                * Cannot direct SET UI elements in background thread
                * so do with runOnUiThread()
                */
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    textOut2.setText(msgInBackGround);
                }});
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //In UI thread, you can access UI here
            textOut3.setText("onPostExecute");
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            //In UI thread, you can access UI here
            progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

    }
}
```

Hopefully it will help you. You can find complete working examples in web. See them for comprehensive understanding about `asynctask`.

**UPDATE**: For achieving synchronization in between `doInBackground()` and `publishProgress()`, you can use synchronization block on some global object or you can use a simple flag to hold executation of `doInBackground()` which is called busy waiting.

**Synchronized Block**:

```
protected List<Data> doInBackground(String... params) {

    synchronize(data) // data is some global object
    {
        // do some job 1
        publishProgress(); // wait until the progress finish
        //do some job 3
    }
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    synchronize(data) // data is the same global object
    {
        // do some job
    }
}
```

**Busy Waiting**: (**not preferred way**)

use a flag `_publishFinished = false;` then call publish progress. Do busy waiting in `doInBackground()` as follows.

```
if(!_publishFinish){
   Thread.Sleep(200); // busy waiting
}
```

at end of onProgressUpdate call

```
_publisFinish = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but my problem is that; `UI` is updated after the second `publishProggress()` method in `while` is executed. I want it to execute after the first `publishProggress()` is executed. They are not waiting each other i guess.

Comment: @eliferdil its not working yet? which publishProgress() is not working!! I believe you can do some trick to handle any special scenario if required :)

Comment: There is an asynchronization. Before `publishProggress()` finishes its job, `doItBackground()` continues and wrong values go. I guess this is how it is supposed to be when using `AsyncTask`. But i need them to be synchronzed. How do I synchronize them? @WasiAhmad

Comment: @eliferdil i guess this is what you are looking for - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893813/can-an-android-asynctask-doinbackground-be-synchronized-to-serialize-the-task-ex

Comment: This is for usage of more than one `AsyncTask`. In my case, the asynchronization is between `doInBackground()` and `publishProggress()`. @WasiAhmad

Comment: @eliferdil what you need is to use synchronize block to hold doInBackground while executing publishProgress(). see this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173569/wait-publishprogress-finish-before-continue-excute-doinbackground-asynctask-andr

Comment: @eliferdil is your problem solved? did you get any help from my updated answer?